# first-class function

Tags: f#

Lets say I have a function

```
 let makeMonitoredFun f =

     let c = ref 0

     (fun x -> c := !c+1; printf "Called %d times.\n" !c; f x);;
```

Why I am not allowed to do this.

```
   let mrev = makeMonitoredFun List.rev
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So presumably you are referring to the value type restriction you get when you try to compile the code.  If you add a type annotation it will work fine/.  For the details of value type errors see this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx from one of the F# developers

Comment: beat me about 1 second ... +1

Comment: So this has to do with syntactic values? Correct me if I am wrong but since makeMonitoredFun List.rev is not a syntactic value then we could replace it with something like fun x -> (makeMonitoredFun List.rev) x and it should work.

Comment: @user1072706 I think you need to do `let mrev x = makeMonitoredFun List.rev x` - but check

Comment: @JohnPalmer I checked both expressions and they are logically correct. The one I stated previously uses a technique called eta expansion. Of course yours is much more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run the following code as the compiler could infer the type of `listRevCounter`.

```
let makeMonitoredFun f =
    let c = ref 0
    (fun x -> c := !c+1; printf "Called %d times.\n" !c; f x)

let listRevCounter = makeMonitoredFun List.rev

let revList = listRevCounter [ 1; 2; 3 ]
```

Comment: but now you have constrained the listRevCounter to be of type `int list -> int list` .... that's different from having a perfectly legal declared generic function. - As the compiler (and the article John posted) tells you you can easily fix this but the question was "why you have to fix it" yourself